# Caffe: inner_product_layer.cpp:64] Check failed: K_ == new_K

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I am finetuning CaffeNet on a custom dataset with 44 classes and receive the following error: 
**inner_product_layer.cpp:64] Check failed: K_ == new_K (9216 vs. 12544) Input size incompatible with inner product parameters.**

Can anyone assist on the problem?


**UPDATE**
The problem occurs only when passing image to the trained model.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the number of predictions (`num_output`) the size of your weight blob also changes and you can no longer init it from saved caffemodel. You need to change the name of the layer, then caffe will init it with random weights (according to `filler`) and you can fine-tune from there

Comment: I did change the name of the layer. Actually training goes well. The problem appears when I pass an image to the trained model.